# Reading DBISAM "dat" files from Python

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc

How to read DBISAM data files? I need to do it on linux.

Please give me any links, docs, drivers...

Comment: Alexander, you need to research your problem at least a bit and show what you have found if you wish to avoid down votes and getting questions closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search found that Elevate software back in January said that it was not possible to access DBISAM on Linux. Here is the [Link to the article](http://www.elevatesoft.com/forums?action=view&category=dbisam&id=dbisam_odbc&msg=1865&page=1)

If you can keep your DBISAM files on Windows and you install Elevate Software's ODBC driver as a system DSN then you could on Linux using any ODBC application along with the [Easysoft ODBC-ODBC Bridge](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc_odbc_bridge/index.html) access your data.

Comment: Any updates about that? I'm dealing with the exactly same situation

Comment: @LuisFelipeA.Venezian I had a similar need and just ended up writing a [Python module](https://pypi.org/project/pydbisam/) to read the databases (just raw-data access, it doesn't handle SQL aspect).

Comment: Hi @Linville nice to know that, thanks for share! At the moment i solved my problem by using DBISAM2TXT program but will test your module as soon as i can.

Comment: @Linville I found an old DBISAM 3 file out there. I can't seem to find documentation on the offsets/structure of the .dat file for that version. Do you know if they're out there?